# Better way to iterate / get data from XML?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I'm trying to get data from an XML file using python and BeautifulSoup. 
I have managed to get the data out and formatted the way I want, but I'm trying to improve my knowledge.  My code is working but I keep thinking, there must be an easier way to do it.

My code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'http://localhost:8888/00612-Waoo-Weekly-2019-Mar-11-2019-Mar-18.xml'
url_result = urlopen(url)
raw_data = url_result.read()
xml_soup = soup(raw_data, 'xml')



entities = xml_soup.findAll('entities',{})
entities = entities[0]

channel_entities = entities.findAll('entity', {"name":"*Nord* Radio Nord"})


channel_check_PMT = []


for entity in channel_entities:
    channel_name = entity['name']
    channel_site = entity['site']
    channel_blade = entity['blade']
    channel_interface = entity['interface']


    channel_check_TS_Sync = entity.findAll('check', {"name": "TS sync"})
    channel_check_PAT = entity.findAll('check', {"name": "PAT"})
    channel_check_Continuity = entity.findAll('check', {"name": "Continuity"})
    channel_check_Sync_byte = entity.findAll('check', {"name": "Sync byte"})
    channel_check_Missing_PID = entity.findAll('check', {"name": "Missing PID"})
    channel_check_PMT = entity.findAll('check', {"name": "PMT"})

    channel_check_PMT = channel_check_PMT[0]
    channel_check_PMT = str(channel_check_PMT)
    channel_check_PMT = channel_check_PMT.replace("<data>","").replace("</data>","").replace('<check name="PMT" threshold="99.9500">','').replace("</check>","").replace("\n","")
    channel_check_PMT = channel_check_PMT.strip()
    channel_check_PMT = channel_check_PMT.split(",")
print(channel_check_PMT)
```

The XML file:

```
<entities>
    <entity name="*Nord*" site="" blade="" interface="QAM1" stream="" joinCount="1" entityType="2" serviceType="Digital Radio">
<check name="TS sync" threshold="99.9500">
        <data>090.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,2222.000,</data>
      </check>
      <check name="Sync byte" threshold="99.9500">
        <data>101.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
      </check>
      <check name="PAT" threshold="99.9500">
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
      </check>
      <check name="Continuity" threshold="99.9500">
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
      </check>
<check name="PMT" threshold="99.9500">
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
</check>
<check name="Missing PID" threshold="99.9500">
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
        <data>100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,100.000,</data>
     </check>
    </entity>
```

If i print the result, it gives me this (What, i want)

```
['100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '100.000', '']
```

This result is expected.
The purpose of this script is to get data within each  and append them to 6 different arrays so it can be used later.

As of now, it's working as it should, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [python-guide.org](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/xml/), they have a nice summary of some libraries aiming to make working with XML easier. I personally like [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict), but that's just a matter of preference.